# Move a div with a small square

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want a draggable div. I have a solution, and it works, but i want to drag the div ONLY with a small square

```css
.bat {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #262626;
}

.batdrag {
    cursor: move;
    width: 45px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class=bat>
    <div class="batdrag"></div>
</div>
```

if have this Jquery code :

```
$(function() {
     $(".batdrag").draggable();
});
```

but it only moves the blue div and I want to move the grey div with the blue one. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in `handle` setting to achieve this. Select the `.bat` element and define `draggable()` on that, then set `.batdrag` as the handle to move the outer element around:

```js
$(".bat").draggable({
  handle: '.batdrag'
});
```

```css
.bat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.batdrag {
  cursor: move;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="bat">
  <div class="batdrag"></div>
</div>
```